# Scraping forum using BeautifulSoup and display in a tabluar form

Tags: beautifulsoup

How do I code BeautifulSoup to display the results in a tabluar format?
something like this:

```
Topic              | Views   | Replies
---------------------------------------
XPS 7590 problems  |  557    |   8    
SSD not working    |  76     |   3
```

My code is:

```
import requests, re
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas as pd

r = requests.get("https://www.dell.com/community/XPS/bd-p/XPS")

soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content)

g_data = soup.find_all("div", {"class": "lia-component-messages-column-thread-info"})

for item in g_data:
    print (item.find_all("h2", {"class": "message-subject"})[0].text)
    print (item.find_all("span", {"class": "lia-message-stats-count"})[0].text) #replies
    print (item.find_all("span", {"class": "lia-message-stats-count"})[1].text) #views
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just construct a dataframe by initializing an empty one and append each "row" into it:

```
import requests, re
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas as pd

r = requests.get("https://www.dell.com/community/XPS/bd-p/XPS")

soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content)

g_data = soup.find_all("div", {"class": "lia-component-messages-column-thread-info"})

df = pd.DataFrame()
for item in g_data:
    topic = item.find_all("h2", {"class": "message-subject"})[0].text.strip()
    replies = item.find_all("span", {"class": "lia-message-stats-count"})[0].text.strip() #replies
    views = item.find_all("span", {"class": "lia-message-stats-count"})[1].text.strip() #views

    df = df.append(pd.DataFrame([[topic, views, replies]], columns=['Topic','Views','Replies']), sort=False).reset_index(drop=True)
```

**Output:**

```
print (df)
                                                Topic Views Replies
0                                  FAQ Modern Standby  1057       0
1                                     FAQ XPS Laptops  4315       0
2         Where is the Precision Laptops Forum board?   624       0
3                    XPS 15-9570, color banding issue  5880     192
4                                 XPS 7590 problems..   565       9
5   XPS 13 7390 2-in-1 Display and Touchscreen issues    17       2
6         Dell XPS 9570 I7-8750H video display issues     9       0
7                      XPS 9360 Fn lock for PgUp PgDn    12       0
8                            Dell XPS DPC Latency Fix  1724       4
9   XPS 13 7390 2-in-1, Realtek drivers lead to fr...   253      11
10      XPS 12 9q23  Touch screen firmware update fix    36       1
11  Dell XPS 15 9570 when HDMI plugged in, screen ...    17       0
12  XPS 13 7390 2 in 1 bluetooth keyboard and mous...   259      10
13                            xps15 7590 wifi problem    46       1
14  Unable to update Windows from 1803 to 1909 - X...    52       5
15  Dell XPS 9300 - Thunderbolt 3 Power Delivery I...    28       0
16  Dell XPS 15 9560, right arrow key or right of ...    26       0
17         XPS 13 2020 (9300) Ubuntu sudden shut down    24       0
18                       Dell XPS 15 9750 won’t login    26       0
19  XPS 13 9360 Windows Hello Face - reconfigurati...    29       2
20  Enclosure for Dell XPS 13 9360 512 GB pcie nvm...   181       7
21  XPS 13 7390 Firmware 1.3.1 Issue - Bluetooth /...   119       2
22                                       SSD Onboard?    77       3
23   XPS 13 9350 only turns on when charger connected  4090      11
24                      Integrated webcam not working    45       1
25  Docking station for XPS 15 9570, Dell TB16 not...    53       4
26                                   Dell XPS 13 9370    34       1
27                XPS 13 9380 overheat while charging   602       3
28    DELL XPS 13 (9300) REALTEK AUDIO DRIVER PROBLEM   214       2
29                    XPS 15 9570 freezing Windows 10   222       6
30                  XPS 13 (9300) - Speaker Vibration    40       2
31  Dell XPS 15 9570 Fingerprint reader not workin...   158       2
32                   XPS 9570 Intel 9260 No Bluetooth    34       0
```

Comment: Oh Nice and Clean! Great! Thank you! that's exactly what I wanted to do. however when i execute the query by print (df) it just output 1 row. which is: 

                                               Topic Views Replies
0  XPS 13 7390 2-in-1 Display and Touchscreen issues    39       3

Comment: oh! please disregard. it is working perfectly. Awesome! Thank you!